# Ctrl+D on a word in Sublime Text in Brackets

Tags: sublimetext2, adobe-brackets

I have been a user of sublime text, but now brackets has a lot of new features. The one that I cannot seem to be able to find is the multiple selection that you get from ctrl+D or cmd+D (mac)

Comment: What was the question?  Are you looking for a feature in Adobe Brackets that you know from SublimeText or vice-versa?

Comment: yes it is a feature in sublime text that I have been unable to replicate in adobe brackets

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in SublimeText is "Quick Add Next."

This appears to be equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in Brackets, which is "Add next match to Selection" on the Find menu.

Answer (score 2):

This works: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in Bracket is not the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in Sublime text.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful, a set of key map overrides for Sublime users in Brackets, navigate to Debug -> Open User key Map and enter these (Windows users afaik):

```
"overrides": {
    "Ctrl-Shift-L": "edit.splitSelIntoLines",
    "Ctrl-Alt-Up": "edit.addCursorToPrevLine",
    "Ctrl-Alt-Down": "edit.addCursorToNextLine",
    "Ctrl-Shift-D": "edit.duplicate",
    "Ctrl-Shift-K": "edit.deletelines",
    "Ctrl-D": "cmd.addNextMatch",
    "Alt-Shift-1": "cmd.splitViewNone",
    "Alt-Shift-2": "cmd.splitViewVertical",
    "Alt-Shift-8": "cmd.splitViewHorizontal",
    "Ctrl-R": "navigate.gotoDefinition",
    "Ctrl-P": "navigate.quickOpen"
}
```

Or just use the Ctrl-D one if that's all that you need!